# Single channel 4-20 mA current loop transmitter

Tags: adc, power-electronics, dac, 4-20ma

I'm designing a single channel 4-20 mA current loop transmitter using XTR111 IC.
By following the reference design guide from TI.

link:  https://www.ti.com/lit/pdf/tidub12

Circuit schematic reference:
https://www.ti.com/lit/pdf/tidrwl8

In the schematic, why the REF5050AIDGKT voltage reference IC is used?
What is the purpose of it?

Power source: 24 V local power supply

Can't I give a 3.3 V supply from my external LDO to DAC VDD that is derived from the same 24 V supply and voltage to DAC Vref pin from the Vreg pin of XTR111?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> *Can't I give a 3.3v supply from my external LDO to DAC VDD that is
> derived from the same 24v supply and voltage to DAC Vref pin from the
> Vreg pin of XTR111?*

Yes you can but, how much accuracy deviation are you prepared to tolerate in your design; a voltage regulator that provides a voltage reference to a DAC is normally the most desirable approach when it comes to accuracy and drift minimization.

Comment: So I can connect both Vdd and Vref to LDO output(3.3v). But the datasheet says Vreg pin of XTR111 should be connected to DAC Vdd.

Comment: Please use part number references in the schematic you linked to avoid ambiguity. Please also link the data sheet and page number that says what you said.

Comment: Part no. (Voltage Reference—REF5050A) IC from page no. 6 from the first link is unavailable locally, so what should be the alternate method to proceed?

Comment: I thought that question was answered in my answer above.